# How to get only distinct values from list

Tags: kql

What I have: A datasource with a string column, let's call it "name".
There are more, but those are not relevant to the question.

The "name" column in the context of a concrete query contains only 2 distinct values:

1. ""
2. "SomeName"

But any of the two a varying amount of times. There will *only* be those two.

Now, what I need is: In the context of a `summarize` statement, I need a column filled with the two distinct values `strcat`ed together, so I end up with just "SomeName".

What I have is not meeting this requirement and I cannot bring myself to find a solution for this:

```
datatable(name:string)["","SomeName","SomeName"] // just to give a minimal reproducible example
| summarize Name = strcat_array(make_list(name), "")
```

which gives me

```
 | Name
> SomeNameSomeName
```

but I need just

```
 | Name
> SomeName
```

I am aware that I need to do some sort of "distinct" somehow and somewhere or maybe there is a completely different solution to get to the same result?

So, my question is: What do I need to change in the shown query to fullfill my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[take_any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-any-aggfunction)

> When the function is provided with a single column reference, it will
> attempt to return a non-null/non-empty value, if such value is
> present.

```
datatable(name:string)["","SomeName","SomeName", ""]
| summarize take_any(name)
```

| name |
| --- |
| SomeName |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjbzE3FSr4pKizLx0zWglJR2l4PzcVD%20gIApTQUkplperRqG4NDc3sSizKlWhJDE7NT4xrxJsgCYA%20uStElAAAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, just as I posted the question, I found an answer:

```
datatable(name:string)["","SomeName","SomeName", ""]
| summarize Name = max(name)
```

I have no idea, why this works for a string column, but here I am.

This results in my desired outcome:

```
  | Name
>   SomeName
```

...which I suppose is probably less efficient than David's answer. So I'll prefer his one.